# Is there an EXCEL formula that detects WHEN/AT WHICH POINT a certain value appears in a row of data?

Tags: excel

Would really appreciate some help with my Excel query.

If I have the following rows of values (always 7 values per row) of data in Excel (3 examples below) where data is coded as 1 or 2, does anyone know an Excel formula which can; detect WHEN in the row, the FIRST 1 appears?

For example;

2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1. (1 first appears at point 2)

2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1. (1 first appears at point 4)

2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2. (1 first appears at point 3)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MATCH function:

```
=MATCH(1,A1:G1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Question title is misleading. "Index of first occurrence of a value in a row" would be more accurate.